# What should have in a Scalable logo?

Tags: logo, resolution, file-format, artboard, dpi

I'm just having different ideas about the **logo size**. Some places say it must be 800×800 px and 72 dpi.

**What's the artboard size** I choose first? **What are resolutions** I should use? What is the **best DPI amount** I should use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illustrator: which artboard size for logo design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99214/illustrator-which-artboard-size-for-logo-design)

Answer (score 4):

Start building the logo in a vector application, and worry about artboard size and resolution later: with a vector format logo, your artwork will be scalable to ANY artboard size and ANY resolution.

Don't know what a vector application is? Here's a list of the more popular ones:

- [Alternative to Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80)

Is Photoshop a vector application? No.

Comment: Well, Imho, the concept App is a small program, mostly on mobile devices, a phone. I would use an "application". :o)

Comment: Fair enough, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What should have in a Scalable logo?

I will answer you what it should **not** have.

> It must be 800×800 px

It should not have a fixed pixel dimension.

> and 72 dpi.

It should not have a specific PPI resolution.

---

If you use a vector-based program as Lucian commented, you could start with the default artboard, A4, letter for example.

**After** finishing the logo, now you **export** it to a raster image, let us say to 800px width or whatever size you need it.

But that is a different step, the delivery.

> Some places say it must be

This sounds like you are a very specific usage, for example, a "logo for xxxxx template on WordPress" but you do not design a logo based on a specific case, you design a logo to be used in different places.

> and 72 dpi.

A web page does not use dpi, if you need 800px you need 800px regardless of the PPI.